# Windows 10 - "Windows will try to connect to the network" and giant key icon

Tags: networking, windows-10, login-screen

I just upgraded to Win10 x64 and the system is joined to my company's domain.

Occasionally, when I boot up or lock the screen, when I come to log back in, instead of getting a normal login prompt -- a big icon of my user image, with DOMAIN\USERNAME and a password prompt -- I instead get a somewhat different prompt: a big generic key icon, my username, a password prompt, and text that says "Windows will try to connect to the network".

On entering my password in this case, the big key icon remains and the text usually changes to "Connecting to the network", but occasionally it says "Unable to connect to the network, logging on" instead.

Does anyone know in what cases this alternative prompt is shown? One reason I ask is that I have some scheduled tasks set to run at startup, and they only seem to run when I get the normal login prompt and not this giant key prompt. But generally just curious about this behavior and what precisely is going on.

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of experimentation, I discovered that this has to do with the "single sign-on" option under the adapter. It turned out that this option was enabled under my Ethernet adapter (the option also exists for Wifi but was disabled there in my case).

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections, select the adapter, right click, Properties, Authentication tab, Additional settings button. "Enable single sign-on for this network" was enabled. I disabled that and from what I can tell, it's removed this strange alternative login prompt. At least I have yet to see it again since.

Remains to be seen if this cripples my ability to work at all - so far, the adapter still authenticates fine and I have access to the corporate network...